# Узнать выделен ли участок текста в WYSIWYG редакторе жирным или нет

Tags: javascript, android, wysiwyg

В **WYSIWYG** редакторе, а именно [RichEditor](http://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android), для применения к тексту выделения жирным шрифтом выполняю команду:

`document.execCommand("bold", false, null);`

Перешерстив инет так и не нашел команды которой можно получить состояние применено ли выделение `bold` к тексту в точке постановки курсора.

Хочу менять цвет кнопки в зависимости активно или нет выделение текста жирным.

Буду благодарен за любую наводку.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3405074

Comment: @woesss это то что нужно было! Оформите вопрос и я приму его как правильный.

Comment: @woesss ...то есть не  вопрос оформите, а ОТВЕТ.

Comment: Вы можете сами оформить ответ, ибо я этот код не проверял и к тому ответу на en-SO тоже не имею отношения. В ответе укажите ссылку на оригинал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить состояние выделения жирным шрифтом текста в точке постановки курсора в **WYSIWYG** редакторе можно так:

```
function selectionIsBold() {
    var isBold = false;
    if (document.queryCommandState) {
        isBold = document.queryCommandState("bold");
    }
    return isBold;
}
```

*P.S.: Ответ сделан на основе комментария господина @woesss и приведенной им ссылки на ответ с en-SO, а именно  [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404618/identify-whether-the-selected-text-in-a-web-page-is-bold-nor-not/3405074#3405074).*